# Problemas con mysql en hosting

Tags: mysql, c#, hosting

Tengo un problema con la continuidad de la conexión a la base de datos alojada en un hosting principalmente uso una clase en C# que recibe la cadena con la operación o consulta.
El problema es que después de un rato de uso el servidor arroja un error, Error Code: 2003 Unable to connect to localhost;

he revisado y mi limite de conexiones son
SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=1000;
set global max_connections = 250;

en el panel de control del hosting no existe un bloqueo a la dirección ip publica donde proceden las peticiones y esto se agrava cuando hay más usuarios realizando operaciones en la base de datos.
He reducido estos errores utilizando una copia local de la base de datos en mysql pero existen ciertas partes del programa en C# que consultan periódicamente si existen nuevos registros en la base datos en la nube.

```
public void ejecutarOperacion(String comando)
{
    MySqlConnection MyConn2 = null;
    try
    {
        formularios.frmcargas carga = new formularios.frmcargas();
        carga.Show();

        MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection("Server=ipservidor;port=3306;Database=basededatos;Uid=" + usuario_logueado + "; Pwd=password;");

        using (MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(comando, MyConn2))
        {
            var temp = MyConn2.State.ToString();
            if (temp != "Open")
            {
                MyConn2.Open();
            }
            MySqlDataReader MyReader2;

            MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
            MyConn2.Close();
            carga.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

La ayuda del sitio donde tengo alojado el servidor es que dicen que hay muchas conexiones sin cerrar pero en la instrucción de la conexión cierro la operación. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si tu arquitectura es cliente-servidor, no deberías abrir una conexión por cada operación, sino abrir y cerrar **una** conexión junto con la aplicación.